# How to deal with overlapping streams for reactive extensions?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactive

Suppose I have a series of like this:

```
X - X - A - B - C - X - X
```

I am interested in two events:

1-) if `A - B - C` occurs sequentially.

2-) if `B - C` occurs sequentially AND if `A - B - C` does not occur.

Accordingly I will subscribe.

For example if  `A - B - C` occurs I will print only **ABC** but not **BC**, whereas if  `X - B - C` occurs then I will print **BC**.  How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

If your source is `IObservable<char>` then try these:

```
IObservable<string> query1 =
    source
        .Publish(ss =>
            ss
                .Zip(ss.Skip(1), (s0, s1) => new { s0, s1 })
                .Zip(ss.Skip(2), (s01, s2) => new { s01.s0, s01.s1, s2 }))
        .Where(s => s.s0 == 'A' && s.s1 == 'B' & s.s2 == 'C')
        .Select(s => String.Join("", s.s0, s.s1, s.s2));

IObservable<string> query2 =
    source
        .Publish(ss =>
            ss
                .Zip(ss.Skip(1), (s0, s1) => new { s0, s1 })
                .Zip(ss.Skip(2), (s01, s2) => new { s01.s0, s01.s1, s2 }))
        .Where(s => s.s0 != 'A' && s.s1 == 'B' & s.s2 == 'C')
        .Select(s => String.Join("", s.s1, s.s2));
```

Comment: Great but can it be done without the not condition s0 != 'A'  as I want these queries to be independent from each other?

Comment: @OnurGumus - I'm not sure what you mean by "independent from each other"?

Comment: assume that query2 doesn't know if query 1 utilizes A. It can be any letter. So I am trying to write query2 based on query1 as reference without query2 being aware of internals of query1. In other words, if somehow query one starts using Z instead of A, the code for query 2 should not change.

Comment: @OnurGumus - My `query1` and `query2` are independent of each other already.

Comment: Yes but query2 is aware of 'A' and uses a not condition. if we look at the definition of query2, there is no mention of A. It  should work if query 1 fails only.

Comment: @OnurGumus - Oh, I see. You don't want them to be independent - you want them to dependent on each other.

Comment: @Enigmativtiy another question is, is there a particular reason you have used Publish as a lambda for this case?

Comment: @OnurGumus - Yes, because this form of `.Publish` allows you to use multiple instances of the same source observable within the lambda, such that only one subscription is made to the source observable, and ensuring that the event happen in the correct sequence. It's very handy as your find that queries that don't work as you expect them to suddenly do when you share the source observable in this way.